# getting mail on my mac from my msn web site

Tags: macos, entourage

I have an email address attached to my web site business name. Is there a way I can get email from this unique address on my mac?  I was able to get email from this unique address on my pc through an outlook connector but I"m not sure this can apply in the mac environment.  I do have entourage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in mail.app.
open mail.app ->preferences-> accounts 
click on the plus sign  this adds an additional account to the mail.app

you will be asked to add the account name -> "click on create account"
then you will need to add account information -> click on test account
if it passes the test  it is ready to use.

good thing is you will have both accounts accessible, bad thing is they will be interspersed with the other emails. and you will also have a tab that you need to click to choose which email account and which smtp server you want to use.

hope this helps